# Can't space correctly using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make responsive blog post. Everything works fine, but I don't like the way it looks. I would like to have a solution when my blog post with image itself would be centered. On desktop version it is less visible, but on mobile device it looks ugly... I'm currently using bootstrap 4, but if you got solutions with css, I also would be really happy!
I need something like on the image:

Desktop version
[image: desktop version]

Mobile version
[image: mobile version]

Here is my html + bootstrap model:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <article class="media content-section">
    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}" alt="">
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="article-metadata">
        <a class="mr-2 author_title" href="{% url 'user-posts' object.author.username %}">@{{ object.author }}</a>
        <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted|date:"N d, Y" }}</small>

        <div>
          <!-- category section -->
          <small class="text-muted">
            Categories:&nbsp;
            {% for category in post.categories.all %}
            <a href="{% url 'blog_category' category.name %}">
              {{ category.name }}
            </a>&nbsp;
            {% endfor %}
          </small>
        </div>

        {% if object.author == user %}
          <div>
            <a class='btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1' href="{% url 'post-update' object.id %}">Update</a>
            <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1' href="{% url 'post-delete' object.id %}">Delete</a>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      </div>

      <img class="img-fluid center" id="rcorners3" src="{{ object.image.url }}" alt="none">
      <h2 class="article-title text-center">{{ object.title }}</h2>
      <p class="article-content">{{ object.content }}</p>
    </div>
  </article>
{% endblock content %}
```

And some code from base.html block:

```
<main role="main" class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          {% if messages  %}
            {% for message in messages %}
              <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}"> <!--grabbing bootstrap tag for displaying alert, info etc. -->
                {{ message }}
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
          {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="content-section">
            <h3>Sidebar</h3>
            <p class='text-muted'>Explore smth new today!
              <ul class="list-group article-metadata">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light"><a class="author_title" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Latest Posts</a></li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light"><a class="author_title" href="">Links</a></li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
              </ul>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: What templating language are you using?  And where do you run it?

Comment: There are quite a few classes in your code, including (but not limited to) `article-img` & `media-body`. If any of these classes relate to styling then please include their CSS

Comment: @inpurforcolor `article-img` class is only for styling image, nothing special, `media-body` is classic bootstrap class (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/media-object/#example)

Comment: @Adriano I'm using bootstrap 4  and a little bit of css for styling. That's all. All my back-end on Django framework

Comment: @CODE If possible, I think you have to apply another bootstrap layout inside your `<article>` tag.  Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/tyqfzum1/ . I don't know if you still want to keep the original layout on desktop view or same as mobile view, it can be tricky depending on your desire.

Comment: @Yunhai Thank you for your answer. I need a solution that is shown on the image. I need mobile and desktop version content to be centered, but it seems like the "column" where _users picture_ is placed prevents centering the content

Comment: @CODE as I said, the issue comes from how you structure `<article><img /*user icon*/ /><div class="media-body" /*main content*/><article>`. Since all of your contents are inside the `media-body`, the centering will always respect to the div. 
So you might want to change the layout like `<article><div class="article-head" /*row1*/>/*Place user icon and your header information */</div>    <div class="article-content" /*row2*/> /*information and the img you want to center*/</div> </article>` , and change the css style as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved this solution like this:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <article class="media content-section">
    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}" alt="">
    <div class="article-metadata">
      <a class="mr-2 author_title" href="{% url 'user-posts' object.author.username %}">@{{ object.author }}</a>
      <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted|date:"N d, Y" }}</small>

      <div>
        <!-- category section -->
        <small class="text-muted">
          Categories:&nbsp;
          {% for category in post.categories.all %}
          <a href="{% url 'blog_category' category.name %}">
            {{ category.name }}
          </a>&nbsp;
          {% endfor %}
        </small>
      </div>

      {% if object.author == user %}
        <div>
          <a class='btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1' href="{% url 'post-update' object.slug %}">Update</a>
          <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1' href="{% url 'post-delete' object.slug %}">Delete</a>
        </div>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
      <img class="img-fluid center" id="rcorners3" src="{{ object.image.url }}" alt="none">
      <h2 class="article-title text-center">{{ object.title }}</h2>
      <p class="article-content">{{ object.content }}</p>
    </div>
  </article>
{% endblock content %}
```